# how to create a filter to search for a word with special characters while writing in the input without special characters

Tags: regex, vuejs2

it's my first post.
I work to Quasar (Vue.js)
I have list of jobs, and in this list, i have words with special caractere.

Ex :

> ```
>    [ ...{ "libelle": "Agent hôtelier" },{"libelle": "Agent spécialisé / Agente spécialisée des écoles maternelles -ASEM-"},{ "libelle": "Agriculteur / Agricultrice" },{ "libelle": "Aide aux personnes âgées" },{ "libelle": "Aide de cuisine" },...]
> ```

And on "input" i would like to search "Agent spécialisé" but i want to write "agent specialise" (without special caractere) or the initial name, i want to write both and autocomplete my "input".
I just don't fin the solution for add to my filter code ...

My input :

> 

```
  <q-select
    filled
    v-model="model"
    use-input
    hide-selected
    fill-input
    input-debounce="0"
    :options="options"
    hint="Votre métier"
    style="width: 250px; padding-bottom: 32px"
    @filter="filterFn"
  >
  </q-select>
</div>
```

My code :

```
    export default {
      props: ['data'],
      data() {
        return {
          jobList: json,
          model: '',
          options: [],
          stringOptions: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        jsonJobsCall(e) {
          this.stringOptions = []
          json.forEach(res => {
            this.stringOptions.push(res.libelle)
          })
        },
        filterFn(val, update) {
          if (val === '') {
            update(() => {
              this.jsonJobsCall(val)
              this.options = this.stringOptions
            })
            return
          }
          update(() => {
            const regex = /é/i
            const needle = val.toLowerCase()
            this.jsonJobsCall(val)
            this.options = this.stringOptions.filter(
              v => v.replace(regex, 'e').toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1
            )
          })
        },
      }
    }
```

To sum up : i need filter for write with or witouth special caractere in my input for found in my list the job which can contain a special character.

I hope i was clear, ask your questions if i haven't been.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What does work / what does not work?

Comment: In fact my code does: - I can write with or without a capital letter - I can write with "e" to search for "é" but not both .. I need to write both, write "e" or "é "to find a word that contains an" é ". To sum up i need the customer write " é "," è "," ê "," Ê " or " e " and find the correct word which contains "é"
Merci. -

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its work for you but you can use regex to create valid filter for your need. For example, when there is "e" letter you want to check "e" or "é" (If I understand correctly)

```
//Lets say we want to match "Agent spécialisé" with the given search text
let searchText = "Agent spe";

// Lets create a character map for matching characters
let characterMap = {
    e: ['e', 'é'],
    a: ['a', '@']
}


// Replacing special characters with a regex part which contains all equivelant characters 
// !Remember replaceAll depricated
Object.keys(characterMap).forEach((key) => {
    let replaceReg = new RegExp(`${key}`, "g")
    searchText = searchText.replace(replaceReg, `[${characterMap[key].join("|")}]`);
})

// Here we create a regex to match
let reg = new RegExp(searchText + ".*")
console.log("Agent spécialisé".match(reg) != null);
```

Another approach could be the reverse of this. You can normalize "Agent spécialisé". (I mean replace all é with normal e with a regex like above) and store in the object along with the original text. But search on this normalized string instead of original.